# Cutting geometries into pieces using boost

Tags: c++, boost, geometry, boost-geometry

Is there any built-in instrument in `boost::geometry` to cut geomtries like on the picture below? My idea is to find an intersection geometries, and substract them from both sources. But it feels like not the best solution, when there's more than 2 intersecting rectangles that shares same area.

[image: cut result]

[image]

So, translating the input data to a isomorphic test case in code:

**<kbd>[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/dc21c8a9b87adacd)</kbd>**

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/io/io.hpp>
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = bg::model;

using point = bgm::d2::point_xy<int>;
using poly  = bgm::polygon<point>;
using mpoly = bgm::multi_polygon<poly>;

int main()
{
    poly a, b, c;
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 0 6 6 6 6 0 0 0))", a);
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((4 -1 4 4 5 4 5 -1 4 -1))", b);
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((3 -3 3 3 9 3 9 -3 3 -3))", c);

    std::cout << bg::wkt(a) << "\n";
    std::cout << bg::wkt(b) << "\n";
    std::cout << bg::wkt(c) << "\n";

    {
        std::ofstream svg("output.svg");
        boost::geometry::svg_mapper<point> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
        mapper.add(a);
        mapper.add(b);
        mapper.add(c);

        mapper.map(a, "fill-opacity:0.2;fill:rgb(0,0,153);stroke:rgb(0,0,200);stroke-width:2");
        mapper.map(b, "fill-opacity:0.2;fill:rgb(153,0,0);stroke:rgb(200,0,0);stroke-width:2");
        mapper.map(c, "fill-opacity:0.2;fill:rgb(0,153,0);stroke:rgb(0,200,0);stroke-width:2");
    }
}
```

Which reflects the following SVG:

[image]

Comment: Do you have a sample that matches the case you "worry" about? It's not clear to me what exactly is meant with "that shares same area" that is not depicted

Comment: @sehe, updated description

Comment: Seen it, added some code to make it more tangible.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the following code:

```
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/point_xy.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry/geometries/multi_polygon.hpp>
#include <boost/geometry.hpp>

#include <boost/foreach.hpp>
#include <boost/foreach.hpp>


namespace bg  = boost::geometry;
namespace bgm = bg::model;

typedef  bgm::d2::point_xy<int> point;
typedef  bgm::polygon<point> poly;
typedef  bgm::multi_polygon<poly> mpoly;

int main()
{
    poly a, b, c;
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((0 0 0 6 6 6 6 0 0 0))", a);
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((4 -1 4 4 5 4 5 -1 4 -1))", b);
    bg::read_wkt("POLYGON((3 -3 3 3 9 3 9 -3 3 -3))", c);

    std::vector<poly> polies;
    polies.push_back(a);
    polies.push_back(b);
    polies.push_back(c);

        std::vector<poly> res;
        for (size_t i = 0; i < polies.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = i; j < polies.size(); ++j)
            {
                boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<poly> output;
                boost::geometry::union_(polies[i], polies[j], output);

                for (auto it = output.begin(); it != output.end(); ++it)
                {
                    res.push_back(*it);
                }    
            }
        }

        for (size_t i = 0; i < polies.size(); ++i)
        {
            for (size_t j = i; j < polies.size(); ++j)
            {
                boost::geometry::model::multi_polygon<poly> multi;
                boost::geometry::sym_difference(polies[i], polies[j], multi);

                for (auto it = multi.begin(); it != multi.end(); ++it)
                {
                    res.push_back(*it);
                }
            }
        }


    {
        std::ofstream svg("output2.svg");
        boost::geometry::svg_mapper<point> mapper(svg, 400, 400);
        size_t i = 0;
        BOOST_FOREACH(poly& p, res)
        {
            std::stringstream ss;
            ss << ++i * 10;
            std::stringstream ss2;
            ss2 << 255 - i * 10;
            mapper.add(p);
            mapper.map(p, "fill-opacity:0.2;fill:rgb("+ ss.str() + "," + ss2.str() +",153);stroke:rgb(0,0,200);stroke-width:2");
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Which produces the following output:
[image]
For this, you have to run over all combinations and compute the unions and sym_differences of the initial polygons.

Sorry, the coloring is not as nice as yours.

Does this help?

Comment: @sehe I cannot take from the question that the OP is aware of the functionality. On the mappter of link-only answer: am I supposed to copy the content? I am not even sure this would be legal. What would be the correct approach on SO? I can also delete the answer if it does not comply with SO approach. Wasn't aware of it

Comment: @sehe Would you mind to give me some feedback on this edit of the answer? Your previous post helped big time. Thank you.

Comment: Almost. There's a couple extra intersection polygons in the result vector. As you can see on the second picture, it should be 7 polygons. Usin this solution I got 9. Thanks anyway, I'll try to make my way from this point

Comment: @user1496491You are right. Sorry. I changed the code to produce the desired output. Can you check?